# How do I export several days or events on my calendar as text?

Tags: calendar, samsung-galaxy-s-6, google-calendar

Using the calendar app, Google calendar or any other calendar app, I can share any one event as text. Is it possible to share/export several events at once? A whole day? Some days? The entire calendar?

Not sure if this matters but I'm using S6 Edge+

Answer (score 2):

It seems like by using Google Calendar app, an edit can happen on specific event and multiple event editing is not supported.

Below are the steps mentioned in [official page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37161?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1) of Android cal. app

- Open the Google Calendar app Google Calendar.
- Open **the event you want to add people t**o.
- Tap Edit Edit.
- Tap Invite people.
- Type the name or email address of the person you want to invite.
- Tap Save.

Of course you can invite multiple guests/people to a specific event, but editing multiple event (to share it) does not seems possible at this time via Google Calendar app.

But if you are using Google calendar on Computer, it seems it is possible to share the whole calendar. You can read the instructions for this on the [official page](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en), but below are the basic steps.

- Open Google Calendar on a computer.
- On the left, find Drop-down menu My Calendars. You may need to click to expand it.
- Find the calendar you want to share and click the arrow next to it.
- Menu on hover over calendar name
- Select Share this Calendar.
- Under Share with specific people, add the email address of the person you want to share with.
- For Permission Settings, choose an option in the drop-down menu. Learn more about these options below.
- Click Add person, if they aren't already added.
- Click Save.

If you shared your calendar with an individual email address, they'll see your calendar in their "Other calendars" list. If you shared your calendar with an email group , they'll see the calendar in their "Other calendars" list once they click on the link in the email invitation from Google Calendar.

Comment: I guess I could share the calendar but I would like to export the calendar to text. Have you really not seen anything like that other than exporting the events individually?

Comment: @BCLC `export the calendar to text` I am not sure of this use case, and how it is useful. when I share the event, it is received as a notification in google account, with option of Yes/No/Maybe etc. to respond to that event. Not sure exporting as plain text can help achieve the same. Can you explain why you need to export the event as text?

Comment: I just wanna share to text without going through the hassle of collecting/giving email addresses, syncing etc. I mean why would anyone want to export a single event to text? So same reason for exporting multiple events to text

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround but does the job

- Log in to [gcal2excel](https://app.gcal2excel.com/exporter#advanced) using your Gmail. It is a free service for first month, with professional features . After the first month you can continue free in [basic mode](https://www.gcal2excel.com/plans/), which likely suffice for the requirements you mentioned ( example below uses Mozilla, you can use Chrome too)
- Select options to filter ( in the screenshots below I have selected Holiday list and not other details for obvious reasons ) and in export file formats choose`html`

[image]
[image]

- Email or download the `html` file, open with inbuilt html viewer or   [any html viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.vineetsirohi.htmlreader),  copy and paste into your [text editor of choice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.byteexperts.texteditor)

[image]

Comment: Oh free for first month. Hmmm...with chrome in desktop can we export to text?

Comment: 10 exports every 3 months? Um...

Comment: Yeah... Depends on how badly you need it. Unfortunate, it isn't fully free. There is no app I could find in alternatives to play store also nor any method on XDA

Answer (score -1):

[Super Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts) can export calendar events in xml. Or you can try [Davdroid](https://davdroid.bitfire.at/configuration) app.

Comment: Please elaborate on how the `xml` file' is to be converted to `txt` file ( which is the OP's requirement) using the first app and how to proceed with the other alternative.

Comment: Also please explain how your solution can be used to export *selected* events (OP asked for date ranges). I don't know how *Super Backup* is supposed to achieve that – but I know for sure DAVDroid does *not* provide that feature (I'm using DAVDroid myself, it's for synchronisation of calendars and contacts, not for exporting them – if you check the URL you've posted, you will see that).